# Relational Algebra Banking Database

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, relational-algebra

I have this relational schema for a banking database

```
Customer(custid PK, name, city, streetaddr, province)

Account(acctid PK, custid, atype, startdate, balance, branchid), (custid ref Customer, branchid ref Branch)

Branch(branchid PK, mgrid, city, streetaddr, province), (mgrid ref Employees.empid)

Employees(empid PK, name, branchid, salary, city, streetaddr, province), (branchid ref Branch)

Transactions(tid PK, acctid, transtype, transdate, transamount, branchid) (acctid ref Account, branchid ref Branch)
```

> I'm trying to find all "savings" account ids, name of the customer, and customer ids, of customers who only made one transaction this year

Obviously I need to use the tables Transactions, Account, and Customer. I joined Accounts with Transactions to see all the accounts that have made one or more transactions, but I'm having trouble with finding the specification of "only one" transaction. I feel like I need to use set difference, but am still unable to think it through.

Comment: Please give a reference to what relational algebra you mean. Even *relations* differ let alone operators. I answered your question in SQL, but I can give a RA version if you communicate the relevant notions of relation & operators.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe:

```
select a.acctid, c.custid, c.name
from account a
inner join (
    select acctid
    from transactions
    where year(transdate) = year(curdate())
    group by acctid
    having count(tid) = 1
) t on a.acctid = t.acctid
inner join customer c
on a.custid = c.custid
where a.atype = 'savings';
```

Answer (score 0):

This invovles a "self-`join`". And yes we 'use set difference'.

The `acctids` where there is 1 transaction in a year are those where there are some transactions `MINUS` the ones where there are at least 2. The former are in `Transactions`. The latter are those where `Transactions(tid, acctid, transtype, transdate, transamount, branchid) AND Transactions(tid2, acctid, transtype2, transdate, transamount2, branchid2) AND tid <> tid2`. Ie in `Transactions NATURAL JOIN RESTRICT tid <> tid2 RENAME tid\tid2, transtype\transtype2, transamount\transamount2, branchid\branchid2 Transactions`. (You could `PROJECT` away `transtype`, `transamount`, & `branchid` before the `MINUS` rather than `RENAME` them.)

Probably easiest in SQL is to `group` this year's transactions `by acctid` and select the groups `having count(tid) > 1`. (Which @GurV's answer does.)

However, I'll address 'trouble with finding the specification of "only one" transaction'.

The `acctids` where there is 1 transaction in a year are those where there are some transactions minus the ones where there are at least 2. The former are in `Transactions`. The latter are those among the `t1.acctid`s where `Transactions(t1.tid, ...) and Transactions(t2.tid, ...) and t1.tid <> t2.tid and t1.acctid = t2.acctid and t1.transdate = t2.transdate`. Ie in `Transactions t1 join Transactions t2 on t1.tid <> t2.tid and t1.acctid = t2.acctid where t1.transdate = t2.transdate`.

```
select a.acctid, c.custname, c.custid
from Transactions t
and t.acctid not in (
    select t1.acctid
    from Transactions t1
    join Transactions t2
    on t1.tid <> t2.tid
    and t1.acctid = t2.acctid and t1.transdate = t2.transdate)
join Account a on t.acctid = a.acctid
join Customer c on a.custid = c.custid
where a.atype = 'savings'
and t.transdate = 2017
```

There's no SQL `except` in MySQL, but besides `in` you can also use a `left join` or a `not exists`.